# Turn off Pivot Table Quick Explore in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm hoping this is a stupid question with a simple answer.. as above, is there anyway to turn off the "Quick Explore" function in Excel. This appears when you select an item in a pivot table and click ctrl.

The problems are two fold:

1. My pivot is stragically placed and nicely (in my opinion) designed, and destroying the worksheet with newly placed filters causes a huge headache.
2. I have procedures that run on selection change spefically to assist when selecting the pivot table that also get decimated when selecting the troublesome Quick Explore
3. The biggest problem occurs when you're in a VBA window. If you're typing away and press Ctrl a couple of times - as I often do to get to a point in my code more quickly (ctrl+right for example) the explore tab appears despite not even being in the Excel window. Coupled with the fact that when you press enter the Quick Explore is triggered destroying the entire worksheet with it's nonsense. Not good when you've not saved in a while. Not good when I'm not even in an Excel window (infuriating some might say).
4. The "undo" on quick explore is just Excel's undo. Great for ease of use, but with no actual manual way of un-performing this abomination if undo is greyed out (perhaps my selection change code resets it, perhaps it is the Data Model undo limitations).

I've added my reasoning for the question in case anyone else is having the same problems with this quite ridiculous "in-place" drilldown feature. I understand the benefits of the drill-down, but I also understand the benefits of having a well-presented, readable report that doesn't require it and would like to turn it off!

Thanks in advance anyone.

Comment: might work https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/two-ways-to-disable-excels-pivot-table-drill-down-feature

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and suggestion. Unfortunately, that solution is to disable the drill-down feature rather than the Quick Explore and doesn't work for this particular problem.